# Getting files by create date

Tags: c#

I have an issue to get some files with a range of date. I searched here and found many answers, but i can't solve my problem.

So, I have this method to get those files:

```
DateTime fromDate = tpFrom.Value;
DateTime toDate = tpTo.Value;
var files = new DirectoryInfo(origemPath).GetFiles()
           .Where(
               f => f.CreationTime.Date >= fromDate && 
               f.CreationTime.Date <= toDate);

foreach (var file in files)
{
   ...
}
```

But that get all files, ignoring the where...

fromDate and toDate is a value from a DateTimePicker

Debuging

One file in files:
[image: one file in files]

fromDate value:

[image: fromDate value]

EDIT:

I tried all the answers here, and nothing worked. How I don't need the best performatic method, I solved my problem like this:

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(origemPath).GetFiles();
    foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.CreationTime.Date >= fromDate && file.CreationTime.Date <= toDate)
                {
                   ...
                }

            }
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me (it gets the correct files)

Comment: Can you check narrowing down the difference between fromDate and toDate?

Comment: I put some images showing the values.

Comment: I tried all the answers here, and nothing worked. How I don't need the best performatic method, I solved my problem like this:

Answer (score 1):

If tpFrom and tpTp are Pickers, maybe the following will do the job

```
DateTime fromDate = tpFrom.Value.Date;
DateTime toDate = tpTo.Value.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<string> GetFiles(DateTime toDate, DateTime fromDate, string directoryName)
{
    if (toDate > fromDate)
    {
        List<string> list = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName).ToList();

        return list.Where(f => File.GetCreationTime(f) <= toDate && File.GetCreationTime(f) => fromDate).ToList();
    }
    return new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
private List<string> GetFiles(DateTime toDate, DateTime fromDate, string directoryName)
{
    if (toDate > fromDate)
    {
        List<string> list = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName).ToList();

        return list.Where(f => File.GetCreationTime(f) <= toDate && File.GetCreationTime(f) => fromDate).ToList();
    }
    return new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Where clause does not execute, check this [link.](http://dabas253.wordpress.com/2008/08/10/discovering-linq-to-directoryinfo-fileinfo-but-linq-is-not-sql/) to find out more details about it. In LINQ, execution of a query is usually deferred until the moment when you actually request the data. In the line with files.Count() you actually get the values. Check out more about [LINQ and dererred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

You should try something like the following:

```
      DirectoryInfo diInbox = new DirectoryInfo(location);
  FileInfo[] InboxFiles = diInbox.GetFiles();
    var files = from file in InboxFiles
                where file.CreationTime >= FromDate 
                select file;
    foreach (var file in files){...}
```